# Regular expression match text between tag

Tags: c#, regex

I need a help with regular expression as I do not have good knowledge in it.

I have regular expression as:

```
Regex myregex = new Regex("testValue=\"(.+?)\"");
```

What does **(.+?)** indicate?

The string it matches is `"testValue=123e4567"` and returns `123e4567` as output.

Now I need help in regular expression to match a string  `"<helpMe>123e4567</helpMe>"` where I need 123e4567 as output. How do I write a regular expression for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means:

```
(   Begin captured group
.   Match any character
+   One or more times
?   Non-greedy quantifier
)   End captured group
```

In the case of your regex, the non-greedy quantifier `?` means that your captured group will begin after the first double-quote, and then end immediately before the very next double-quote it encounters. If it were greedy (without the `?`), the group would extend to the very *last* double-quote it encounters on that line (i.e., "greedily" consuming as much of the line as possible).

For your "helpMe" example, you'd want this regex:

```
<helpMe>(.+?)</helpMe>
```

Given this string:

```
<div>Something<helpMe>ABCDE</helpMe></div>
```

You'd get this match:

```
ABCDE
```

The value of the non-greedy quantifier is evident in this variation:

```
Regex: <helpMe>(.+)</helpMe>
String: <div>Something<helpMe>ABCDE</helpMe><helpMe>FGHIJ</helpMe></div>
```

The greedy capture would look like this:

```
ABCDE</helpMe><helpMe>FGHIJ
```

There are some useful interactive tools to play with these variations:

- [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/)
- [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Thanks :) Now i got the output

Comment: Regex myregex = new Regex("<helpMe>(.+?)</helpMe>") WORKED!! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Ken Redler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195594/ken-redler) has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879149/regular-expression-help/4879201#4879201) regarding your first question. For the second question try:

```
<(helpMe)>(.*?)</\1>
```

Using the [back reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `\1` you can find values between the set of matching tags. The first group finds the tag name, the second group matches the content itself, and the `\1` back reference re-uses the first group's match (in this case the tag name).

Also, in C# you can use named groups, like: `<(helpMe)>(?<value>.*?)</\1>` where now `match.Groups["value"].Value` contains your value.

Answer (score 0):

> What does (.+?) indicate?

It means match any character (.) one or more times (+?)

A simple regex to match your second string would be

```
<helpMe>([a-z0-9]+)<\/helpMe>
```

This will match any character of `a-z` and `any digit` inside `<helpme>` and `</helpMe>`.

The pharanteses are used to capture a group. This is useful if you need to reference the value inside this group later.